# How to allow an apparmor profile to create a unix socket

Tags: apparmor

On Ubuntu kinetic, I get multiple DENIED operations by apparmor in /var/log/syslog such as:

```
operation="create" class="net" info="failed type and protocol match" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" comm="cupsd" family="unix" sock_type="dgram" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
operation="create" class="net" info="failed type and protocol match" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" comm="cupsd" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
```

I tried to allow the creation of such a socket in **/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd** by adding:

```
  unix (create) type=dgram,
  unix (create) type=stream,
```

However, restarting the systemd apparmor and cups services does not solve the issue.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Add those lines into the apparmor profile **/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd**

```
  network unix dgram,
  network unix stream,
```

And then reload apparmor using

```
systemctl reload apparmor
```